# Returning value from lambda in the same line with declaration

Tags: c++, function, c++11, lambda, declaration

Sometimes it is easier to represent a value by function, and lambdas are good for this. But is there any way to return value from lambda declaration?

for example:

```
int i = []{return 2;};
```

generates an error. How to make that lambda declaration return `2` without any new lines of code?

Comment: *"generates error"*: good to show that error in that case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like calling any functions using the calling `operator()`, you need to call the lambda.

```
int i = []{return 2;}();
//                   ^^
```

Answer (score 4):

Addtionaly to the answers provided. This is called an *immediately-invoked function expression* (IIFE), or sometimes, *immediately-invoked lambda expression*. (FF comes from C++ is widely used in other languages)

```
int i = []{return 2;}(); // () invokes the lambda AKA call operator
```